# What property of a hexagon makes it "stackable"?

Tags: geometry

You can stack hexagons, but not octagons, or pentagons(?) in 2D.

( Stackable:~ I am able to arrange hexagons together without any area left between two hexagons)

So what property of a hexagon (in 2D) makes this possible?

How do I get the/all stackable shape(s) in n-dimensions?

Comment: Define "stackable".

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes, in 2D 'tiling' would certainly be more appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: This is assuming a Euclidean plane - note that in a hyperbolic plane, adjusting the size gives more freedom in what the angles of a "regular" polygon can be, so there you can in fact find tilings of octagons or pentagons.

Comment: @MorganRodgers That Wikipedia page led me to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant

Comment: Which is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: You can tile the plane with hexagons because you can tile the plane with equilateral triangles. The only other regular object you can tile the plane with is a square. Non-regular tessellation's exist, but are not tilings in the sense you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an area of much research.  A shape which can fill up the plane with no gaps is said to tesselate, or tile, the plane.  There are an infinite number of shapes which do this in any dimension.  To see this, imagine taking a square, and cutting a shape out of one of its sides.  Now attach it to the opposite side in the same orientation.  Two of these shapes fit together.  You can tile the entire plane.  For regular polytopes, the n-cube works in all dimensions, and other analogues of 3D shapes are spotty in higher dimensions.  For example, the triangle can tile the plane, but the tetrahedron can't tile space.

Comment: Do you have any more questions?  The wiki page for tesselations is helpful.